# Excel: How to pick first zero in row, after a nonzero value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a row of data, how do you find the column where the first zero resides in, after a non-zero value?
[Check this image for the example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX1XC.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(B2:E2)/((A2:D2<>0)*(B2:E2=0)),1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`=FIND("0",TEXTJOIN(,,A2:E2),FIND("1",TEXTJOIN(,,A2:E2)))`

EDIT:

To works with any non-zero value:

```
=INDEX(OFFSET(A2,-(ROW()-1),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:E2<>0,),0),,COLUMNS(A2:E2)-MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:E2<>0,),0)),1,MATCH(0,OFFSET(A2,0,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:E2<>0,),0),,COLUMNS(A2:E2)-MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:E2<>0,),0)),0))
```

Comment: Could be any number, not only 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FindNonZero()

For i = 2 To 4
    For j = 1 To 5
        If Cells(i, j).Value <> 0 Then
            For k = j To 5
                If Cells(i, k).Value = 0 Then
                    Cells(i, 7).Value = "COL" & k
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next k
        Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own function in VBA

```
Function FindZero(TargetRange as range) As Long
   Dim aCell as range 

   For each aCell in TargetRange 
      if aCell>0 AND aCell.Offset(0,1) = 0 then
         FindZero = aCell.Offset(0,1).Column
         Exit For
      end if 
   next aCell
end function
```

And then in some cell you just put

```
=FindZero(A1:G1)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

This INDEX/AGGREGATE/MATCH should do it for you.

```
=INDEX(INDEX(C$1:G$1, 1, AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN(A:E)/(C2:G2>0), 1)):G$1, MATCH(0, INDEX(C2:G2, 1, AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN(A:E)/(C2:G2>0), 1)):G2, 0))
```

Note that COLUMN(A:E) returns the *position within* C$1:G$1 and C2:G2.

[image]